# Application saving textbox state on orientation change?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to understand the total flow of Android applications, and I'm running into what I consider to be a strange situation (note: Im VERY new to android programming).

I made a test application with just a multiline edit text field. I wrote 1234 on the field. Without anything else, with no other changes to the default Eclipse ADT made application and without overriding anything specifically in the backend, I changed orientation. 1234 remained. I then hit the home button, then opened it from recent apps. 1234 remained.

My understanding of the app lifecycle was that the application was stopped and started when the home button is pressed, and the application is destroyed and created when the application's orientation is changed. If this is correct, is there some form of automatic state keeping that takes place? I was under the assumption that I had to pull, from the state bundle, individual variables and restore them myself. Is that not correct?

Any explanation of this that a more seasoned Android dev could give would be great. I've been trying to find the appropriate answer, but to no avail.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.teststate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Activity_Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.teststate.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Snippet from Manifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the view explicitly saves and restores its state on orientation changes, by overriding [View#onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSaveInstanceState()) and [View#onRestoreInstanceStance(Parcelable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Parcelable)). Here's the of the implementation in **TextView** (super class of **EditText**)

```
@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();

    // Save state if we are forced to
    boolean save = mFreezesText;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;

    if (mText != null) {
        start = getSelectionStart();
        end = getSelectionEnd();
        if (start >= 0 || end >= 0) {
            // Or save state if there is a selection
            save = true;
        }
    }

    if (save) {
        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
        // XXX Should also save the current scroll position!
        ss.selStart = start;
        ss.selEnd = end;

        if (mText instanceof Spanned) {
            Spannable sp = new SpannableStringBuilder(mText);

            if (mEditor != null) {
                removeMisspelledSpans(sp);
                sp.removeSpan(mEditor.mSuggestionRangeSpan);
            }

            ss.text = sp;
        } else {
            ss.text = mText.toString();
        }

        if (isFocused() && start >= 0 && end >= 0) {
            ss.frozenWithFocus = true;
        }

        ss.error = getError();

        return ss;
    }

    return superState;
}

[...]

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if (!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        return;
    }

    SavedState ss = (SavedState)state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());

    // XXX restore buffer type too, as well as lots of other stuff
    if (ss.text != null) {
        setText(ss.text);
    }

    if (ss.selStart >= 0 && ss.selEnd >= 0) {
        if (mText instanceof Spannable) {
            int len = mText.length();

            if (ss.selStart > len || ss.selEnd > len) {
                String restored = "";

                if (ss.text != null) {
                    restored = "(restored) ";
                }

                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Saved cursor position " + ss.selStart +
                      "/" + ss.selEnd + " out of range for " + restored +
                      "text " + mText);
            } else {
                Selection.setSelection((Spannable) mText, ss.selStart, ss.selEnd);

                if (ss.frozenWithFocus) {
                    createEditorIfNeeded();
                    mEditor.mFrozenWithFocus = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (ss.error != null) {
        final CharSequence error = ss.error;
        // Display the error later, after the first layout pass
        post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setError(error);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, it saves the state in a `Parcelable` object, which is then passed along to a view with the same `android:id` in the new instance, and `onRestoreInstanceState()` gets called on the new view. If you create a custom view, which doesn't just consists of other views, you might want to override these methods.

Comment: This is perfect. Answers my question exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I am not able to give you a code level explanation. But it is one of those things android promised to do. You can check out this [Recreating activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Note: In order for the Android system to restore the state of the views in your activity, each view must have a unique ID, supplied by the android:id attribute.